# Django Reverse for 'document' with keyword arguments {'title':'computer science'} not found. 1 pattern tried

Tags: python, django

i getting a NoReverseMatch exception but i can't see my mistake.

**Urls file:**

```
url(r'^Demo$', views.demo, name='demo'),
url(r'^Demo/(?P<title>[\w-]+)/$', views.demo_document, name='demo_document'),
url(r'^Document_list$', views.document_list, name='document_list'),
```

**Template:**

```
{% for demotext in demotexts %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'keywordExtraction:demo_document' title=demotext.title %}">{{ demotext.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Views:**

```
def demo(request):
    demotexts = DemoText.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'keywordExtraction/demo.html', {'demotexts': demotexts})


def demo_document(request, title):
    demotext = DemoText.objects.get(title=title)
    demotexts = DemoText.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'keywordExtraction/demo.html', {'demotext': demotext, 'demotexts': demotexts})
```

**Message:**

Reverse for 'demo_document' with keyword arguments '{'title': 'Computer Science'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['KeywordExtraction/Demo/(?P[\w-]+)/$']

/views.py in demo

return render(request, 'keywordExtraction/demo.html', {'demotexts': demotexts})

Local vars

```
Variable     Value

demotexts    <QuerySet [<DemoText: DemoText object (4)>, <DemoText: DemoText object (5)>]>

request      <WSGIRequest: GET '/KeywordExtraction/Demo'>
```

Comment: `'Computer Science'` is *not* a valid slug, a slug has no spaces, it uses hyphens for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `[\w-]+` does not match whitespace. This pattern is used for [*slugs* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/glossary/#term-slug). A slug is a way to render text pleasantly in the browser, since a whitespace is rendered as `%20`, whereas a hyphen is rendered as `-`.

In order to make a slug, you can make use of a [**`SlugField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SlugField), or a [**`AutoSlugField`** [readthedocs]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField), from the [**`django-autoslug`** package [readthedocs]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). `django-autoslug` is probably more convenient.

You can install it in your local environment with:

```
pip install django-autoslug
```

then you can add a slug to your model:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class DemoText(models.Models):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
```

A `SlugField` will by default also add a `db_index` on the column, to allow fast retrieval.

then in your url you can match it, probably it is better to rename the parameter to `slug` to avoid confusion:

```
url(r'^Demo/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.demo_document, name='demo_document'),
```

In the view, you can then match on the `slug`:

def demo_document(request, **slug**):
    demotext = DemoText.objects.get(**slug=slug**)
    demotexts = DemoText.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'keywordExtraction/demo.html', {'demotext': demotext, 'demotexts': demotexts})

and in the template, you render it with slug:

```
{% for demotext in demotexts %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'keywordExtraction:demo_document' slug=demotext.slug %}">{{ demotext.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Likely you will need to populate the database again to generate the slugs.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't understand the pattern.